# Looking for a solution to tape and reeling 01005 components

Tags: resistors, components, surface-mount, packages

Current tape and reel causes 01005 size components to move around. How can I have them packaged so they can retain their original orientation?

I've spoken to many reeling houses, any feedback is appreciated!